# Can Gazebo be told to ignore .svn folders or all hidden folders?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

My models are under SVN version control.  This means a ".svn" folder is placed in all of the directories.  So upon launching Gazeo, I get the error:

`Error [InsertModelWidget.cc:254] model.config file is missing in directory["/home/.../WAMDatabase/.svn"]`.

Is there any way of telling Gazebo to ignore this file so I don't get the error?  It's not a huge deal, but it'd make the legitimate errors stand out more.

**Update:**  Bonus:  ignoring the backup files created by gedit that end in "~".

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2713/can-gazebo-be-told-to-ignore-.svn-folders-or-all-hidden-folders?/) by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 175 on 2013-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The model database specification does not allow for extraneous directories and files. This was done on purpose, especially for the case of version controlled files.

It's possible for Gazebo to download, and change, models within your svn repo. It's not safe to tell gazebo to use models from a version control system.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-07-25**:
Maybe I'm misunderstanding -- is the advice to not version control Gazebo models?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-07-26**:
Version control your models is a good thing. But you should install the models into a location that is not your version control repo and point Gazebo to that installed directory.